# RegExp - How to remove space

Tags: python, regex

```
s = "LEV606 (P), LEV230 (P)"
#Expected result: ['LEV606', 'LEV230']

# First attempt
In [3]: re.findall(r"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}[ \(P\)]?", s)
Out[3]: ['LEV606 ', 'LEV230 ']

# Second attempt. The 'P' is not mandatory, can be other letter.
# Why this doesn't work?
In [4]: re.findall(r"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}[ \([A-Z]{1}\)]?", s)
Out[4]: []

# Third attempt
# White space is still there. Why? I want to remove it from the answer
In [5]: re.findall(r"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}[\s\(\w\)]?", s)
Out[5]: ['LEV606 ', 'LEV230 ']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `[...]` syntax incorrectly; that's a character class, a **set** of characters that can match. Any one character listed in that class is matched, so either a space, or a `(` character, or a `P` or a `)`; that space will do nicely.

Use a non-capturing group instead of the character class to make the extra text optional, and a capturing group for the part you do want to have:

```
re.findall(r"([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3})(?: \(P\))?", s)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "LEV606 (P), LEV230 (P)"
>>> re.findall(r"([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3})(?: \(P\))?", s)
['LEV606', 'LEV230']
```